# Quickbooks API - Can I access Accounting -> Client data?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to understand if the Quickbooks API provides the ability to retrieve data of a users' clients and THEIR associated data.

The scenario would be as follows: API works with multiple accounting firms and the firms have clients with Journal Entries, etc etc.

In QBO Accounting, you can access all of your clients and do what you need.

Based on everything I've seen in the developer documentation, it seems that the APIs simply allow me to pull my own QBO data, not data of any clients that I may have access to. Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access your company's client data. This happens through the oauth2 flow.